# List tests that WOULD be run in testng

Tags: testng

Is there a way to get testng to do a dryrun of the tests and output the package.name.parameters of the tests that would be run without actually running them?  I have a partial solution using `IHookable` which records the test information without ever calling the `IHookCallBack`.  The disadvantage to that approach is that all the `@Before Class/Suite/Test/Method`s get called.  We utilize those quite abit and put a lot of time-consuming functionality in them which I would ideally like to skip.

Comment: Doesn't IMethodInterceptor solve your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with implementing an `IMethodInterceptor`  The constructor of the system under test still gets called, as well as `@BeforeSuite` and `@BeforeTest`.  If the SUT uses a `@Factory` to create multiple instances of itself or another class, that class should implement a property called `String classParameters` which distinguishes it from others.  Also, since `@BeforeClass` is not called, any `@DataProvider`s that relies on having the `@BeforeClass` called will not work properly.

It doesn't feel like the perfect solution, but is good enough for my needs.  Hope this helps someone else.

```
/* DryRunListener.groovy */
import org.testng.IMethodInstance
import org.testng.IMethodInterceptor
import org.testng.ITestContext
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider
import org.testng.annotations.Test

/*
 * This interceptor builds up a list of tests that would run without actually running them
 * The @BeforeMethod and @BeforeClass methods are NOT run, but the @BeforeSuite, @BeforeTest and constructors still run.
 * If data providers rely on the @BeforeClass methods getting called, they won't work
 */
class DryRunListener implements IMethodInterceptor {
    def tests = []

    @Override
    List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        for (method in methods) {
            // Get class name plus any parameters given by factories
            def className = getClassName(method)

            // Handling for data providers. If the method uses one, go invoke it
            def params = getParametersForMethod(method)

            tests = params.collect { "${canonicalName}.$method.method.methodName(${it.join ", "})" }
        }

        tests.each { println it } // or save it or whatever...
        return [] // tells testng - Don't run any methods!
    }

    /*
     * When using factories, there's no way to distinguish instances the factory has created.
     * TestNG has a mechanism whereby you inherit from ITest, and implement a getTestName, which is typically
     * set during a @BeforeMethod call, and is used by reporters. This requires @BeforeMethod actually be called,
     * which we don't want to do from this interceptor. Instead, we ask the testclass to implement a property for
     * returning a serialized string called classParameters, which we will append to the canonicalName of the class
     */
    String getClassName(IMethodInstance method) {
        def realClass = method.method.realClass
        def canonicalName = realClass.canonicalName
        if (realClass.metaClass.hasProperty(method.instance, "classParameters")) {
            canonicalName += "($method.instance.classParameters)"
        }
        canonicalName
    }

    /*
     * The interceptor receives the list of methods before they have been exploded for
     */
    Object[][] getParametersForMethod(IMethodInstance method) {
        def testAnnotation = method.method.constructorOrMethod.method.getAnnotation(Test.class)
        Class dataProviderClass = testAnnotation.dataProviderClass()
        if (dataProviderClass == null || dataProviderClass == Object.class) {
            dataProviderClass = method.method.realClass
        }
        String dataProviderName = testAnnotation.dataProvider()
        def dataProviderMethod = dataProviderClass.methods.find { it.getAnnotation(DataProvider.class)?.name() == dataProviderName }
        return dataProviderMethod?.invoke(method.instance) ?: [[]]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TestNG added this option in version 6.14 (see [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1503)).
To activate it, use the JVM argument:

```
-Dtestng.mode.dryrun=true
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Java Reflection is your best friend. You can use reflections and get all the info. 
2) Other possible solution is convert your testng.xml to programmitacal equivalent using *Xml* classes(XmlTest...). you will find lots of API which can help you to achieve that. 
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Reflection is more like that 2nd cousin you once kissed, and now things are just awkward :-).  Joking aside, to go the reflection route, I would have to duplicate lots of the logic TestNG already does.  It's not as easy as just grabbing the method names tagged with `@Test`.  An incomplete list of problems I'd have to deal with: Inheriting the `@Test` attribute from super classes, throwing out `enabled=false` tests, `@DataProvider`s, `@Factory`s, `dependsOn` to keep the order the same, `groups`, etc.  Sure, all this is possible, as shown by TestNG existing, but I'd rather extend, not rewrite.